# Update a server network configuration information by cloud-init when the server is running

Tags: openstack, cloud-init

In Openstack pike, I used *cloud-init* to init a server through config driver when  the server starts firstly. Now I want to attach a new network to the server, and I want to use *cloud-init* to autoconfigure network information for the new network in this server. How can I do it?

Comment: cloud-init version is 18.3. After I add a new network to this server, the XML file of this server is changed, but the config driver data not change.

Comment: Hi czhen, I suggest to visit [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you improve the quality of your question. The higher the quality, the more chance you have that your question will be answered.

Comment: ok,thank you very much!